# cvlib detect common objects function doesn't work

Tags: python, cvlib

I'm new to cvlib module.....

I tried to use the detect_common_objects function from cvlib module but hit the error below.
I'm using cvlib version 0.2.7 and cv2 version 4.5.3.

```
import cvlib as cv
import cv2
image2019_0=cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Project CV x Traffic/car_image_2019_Jan/0.jpg')
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(image2019_0, model = 'yolov4', enable_gpu = True)
```

error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the latest version of OpenCV (4.5.5.62). You can upgrade the package to the newest version as below

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

If you want to use older version of OpenCV, downgrade cvlib to 0.2.6 as below

```
pip install cvlib==0.2.6
```

The issue you are facing is due to version incompatibility.

Comment: I downgrade cvlib to v0.2.6 and it works! Thanks for your help!